# Conda build for universal PyPI package: which Python versions do I need to build for?

Tags: python, build, anaconda, pypi

I am creating a conda build for a pure Python package based on the respective PyPI package.

In case that matters: The PyPI package is universal, i.e., it has been generated using the command `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --universal` and works with both Python 2 and Python 3.

When I build for conda in a conda environment running a specific Python version like 2.7, the resulting package files also carry that version in their file name.

I know that I can build for several Python variants using [build variants](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/variants.html), e.g., I could build for 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. But should I do that and upload all these package to anacondacloud, or are the resulting packages redundant?

(So far I have uploaded versions for 2.7 and 3.6, and I noticed that when I installed in a Python 3.4 conda environment, conda downloaded Python 3.6. This suggests that I should upload for all versions, but on the other hand when I visit the website for my package on anaconda cloud, there is nothing on there which indicates the different Python versions the package is available for. If it mattered, I would expect to see that information on there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `noarch` option in the `build` section of your meta.yaml file.

```
build:
  number: 0
  noarch: python
...
```

This allows you to upload one conda package that can be used for all versions of Python that you set as compatible in the `requirements` section. See also the [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#architecture-independent-packages)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have two questions left as I cannot find anything on the fact that I have to *list specific Python versions as compatible in the requirements section* in the docs. 1) In which sub section of *requirements* do I have to put them? *build*, *host*, *run* or some combination of the latter? 2) I can use a  conda_build_config.yaml file as explained in the build variants documentation for this, right?

Comment: 1) It depends on how you build your package. If you use `pip` (as recommended by [conda forge](https://conda-forge.org/docs/meta.html#use-pip)), then `python` should be in the `host` and `run` section, but the version limits should only be in the `run` section. For more complicated cases, please ask over on the conda google group. 2) As far as I know, yes.